# how can i translate my html into a pug document?

Tags: html, pug

```
div id='main'

div ..content /div

div ..content /div

div ..content /div

/div

main.style {
width:"250px",
height:"100px",
overflow-y:"scroll"
}
```

//Within the main div I want to add other divs containing content using a for loop. How would one go about this using pug and node.js?

Comment: Have you read the pug docs on [iteration](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) yet?

Answer (score 0):

good to use an array of objects:

```
mixin myMixin(divArray)

  each divElement in divArray
    - const {className, content} = divElement
    .my-class(class=`my-class_${className}`)= content

//- in your main div
- const divArray = [{className: 'name', content: 'Mark'},{className: 'date', content: 'nov 24'},{className: 'day', content: 'sunday'},{className: 'phone', content: '123 4565'}]
.container
  +myMixin(divArray)
```

or a regular array:

```
mixin myMixin(divArray)

  each divContent in divArray
    .item= divContent


.container
  +myMixin(['first', 'second'])
```

possible without mixins:

```
- const divArray = [{className: 'name', content: 'Mark'},{className: 'date', content: 'nov 24'},{className: 'day', content: 'sunday'},{className: 'phone', content: '123 4565'}]

.my-class
  - let i = divArray.length - 1
  while i >= 0
    - const {className, content} = divArray[i--]
    .(class=`my-class__${className}`)= content
```